# Minimise a winform from a usercontrol in C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a C# application which has the main form as Form2.

Within Form2 there is a panel in which several different UserControls dock. The user clicks through until the final 'Complete' button (still within a UserControl on Form2). When this is click, I want Form2 to minimise and Form3 to open.

Form3 opening is no problem, but I don't know how to access Form2's controls from within a UserControl.

I know the code to minimise the form, but not the initial code to get access to the already open instance of Form2.

I don't need any variables passing back and forth, just access to Form2's controls.

I have tried;
Form2 mainForm = new Form2();

But this obviously isn't right as I don't need a new Form2.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: A UserControl has access to a ParentForm property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Control.TopLevelControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Gets the parent control that is not parented by another Windows Forms
>   control. Typically, this is the outermost Form that the control is
>   contained in.

Something like:

```
Form2 f2 = (Form2)this.TopLevelControl; // from within your UserControl
```

Comment: I'm getting : 'Unable to cast object of type 'DWSPanelC.sideBar' to type 'DWSPanelC.Form2'.' DWSPanelC is the app name, sideBar is the 2nd form which I want to minimise Form2 (which is the main app form)

Comment: I made the mistake of putting your code into the wrong form. Once in the usercontrol it worked fine.